# Inherited table in SQL Server 2008. Performance issues?

Tags: sql-server-2008, single-table-inheritance

I have this idea I've been mulling around in my head based on another concept I read somewhere. Basically you have a single "Primary" table with very few fields, other tables inherit that primary table through a foreign key. This much has been done before so its no news. What I would like to do, is to have virtually every table in the database inherit from that Primary table. This way, every object, every record, every entry in every table can have a fully unique primary key(since the PK is actually stored in the Primary table), and can be simply referenced by ID instead of by table.

Another benefit is that it becomes easy to make relationships that can touch multiple tables. For example: I have a Transaction table, and this table wants to have a FK to whatever it is a transaction for(inventory, account, contact, order, etc.). The Transaction can just have a FK to the Primary table, and the necessary piece of data is referenced through that.

The issue that keeps coming up in my head, is whether or not that Primary table will become a bottleneck. The thing is gonna have literally millions of records at one point. I know that gigantic record sets can be handled by good table design, but whats the limit?

Has anyone attempted anything similar to this, and what were your results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider that this table will have a tons of foreign key relations. These can cause performance issues, if you want to delete a row from the root table. (Which can cause some nasty execution plans on delete)

So if you plan to remove rows, then it could impact performance. I recently had issues with a setup like this, and it was a pain to clean it up (it was refferencing 120 other tables - deletes where slow as hell).

To overcome this performance issue, you might consider not enforcing contrains (Bad plan), using no contrains for performance (Bad plan), or try to group all data that belongs to one entity in one row, and stick to the normal normalization practices (Good plan)

Comment: Boy is that true about the deletes. Even if you know that 90% of teh tables wouldn't have the data, the db would still have to check all of them.

Comment: Also locks on this central table will be a pain... Just dont do it ;)

Comment: I figured it was a bad plan, just want 100% sure about everything that was wrong with it. I didn't even think about how the simple act of deleting would be impacted. But thats why you ask right?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the primary table will almost certainly be a bottleneck.
2. How do you enforce real referential integrity?
   For example, How can you be sure that the transaction's FK is actually linked to an inventory, account, contact or order rather than an apple, orange or pineapple?

Comment: the OP's idea is now a built-in feature in entity framework - can't be that awful!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something that would be a horrible bottleneck. Not only that it would make enforcing the real PK/FK relationships much harder. It could create a data integrity nightmare. I don't see where you gain any benefits at all.